# Not able to catch org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, dao, staleobjectstate

Can we not catch the StaleObjectStateException? I have catch block with StaleObjectStateException , so when method is throwing this error it is coming to this catch block but still throwing the same exception again.
I know the reason why this exception is coming but i want to catch the exceptiion and proceed further.

```
[13/05/15 10:00:07:751 BST] 00000053 TaskUtils$Log E org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler handleError Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
                                     org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Object of class [com.lgs.mem.model.MemService] with identifier [3038]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.lgs.mem.model.MemService#3038]
                    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:676)
                    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionSynchronization.translateException(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:160)
                    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionSynchronization.beforeCommit(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:148)
                    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:95)
                    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:927)
                    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager.access$4(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:1)
                    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager$UOWActionAdapter.run(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:338)
                    at com.ibm.ws.uow.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.runUnderNewUOW(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:786)
                    at com.ibm.ws.uow.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.runUnderUOW(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:365)
                    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager.execute(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:281)
                    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:127)
                    at at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy156.updateRetryCountAndTSP(Unknown Source)
    at com.lgs.mem.service.impl.MemDAOServiceImpl.updateRetryCountAndTSP(MemDAOServiceImpl.java:181)
    at com.lgs.mem.scheduler.MEMRecoveryScheduler.processFailedNicheRequests(MEMRecoveryScheduler.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:64)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:452)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:328)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:161)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.TimerManagerTaskScheduler$TimerScheduledFuture.timerExpired(TimerManagerTaskScheduler.java:112)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.TimerManagerTaskScheduler$ReschedulingTimerListener.timerExpired(TimerManagerTaskScheduler.java:165)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.timer.TimerImpl.callListenerMethod(TimerImpl.java:361)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.timer.GenericTimer.run(GenericTimer.java:228)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext$RunProxy.run(J2EEContext.java:265)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:252)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:495)
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:132)
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext$DoAsProxy.run(J2EEContext.java:336)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:280)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext.run(J2EEContext.java:1174)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.timer.TimerImpl.runListenerAsCJWork(TimerImpl.java:490)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.am._Alarm.fireAlarm(_Alarm.java:333)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.am._Alarm.run(_Alarm.java:230)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1659)
Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.lgs.mem.model.MemService#6768]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.check(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1950)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2595)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2495)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2822)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionSynchronization.beforeCommit(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:145)
    ... 38 more
```

Comment: Show the relevant code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can catch the exception.

Problems like this can occur if the exception does not propagate to the place that you are trying to catch it.  For example:

- It may be thrown on a different thread.
- It may be further up the stack, and then re-thrown as a different exception.

Judging from the stacktrace, I'd say that it is the second explanation.  The original exception has been caught and a `HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException` has been created that wraps it.  It is the latter exception you are seeing.

If you want to specifically handle the original exception, you probably need to catch `HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException` (or a superclass), and then call the exception object's `getMostSpecificCause()` to extract the original exception for diagnosis.

Comment: The control is not going to the HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException catch block instead it's going to the StaleObjectStateException and throwing it again, means still i can see the stack trace.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying.  The stacktrace clearly shows that the actual exception that is being logged is an HOLFE, not an SOSE.

Comment: yes, but still exception is throwing out of the method and control is just exiting the method, but i expect to continue the method after catching the exception. I have read it some where lik this HOLFE will be thrown out of the transaction.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are saying.  If the HOLFE exception is causing the method call to terminate a method, that means that the method didn't catch it.  That is just normal Java exception behaviour.

Comment: I have added the catch block in out side the transaction and it's catching and working as expected, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW,readOnly=true)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.